# ViewBag not working as it should in the partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I cannot use a `ViewBag` value in my partial view from my controller class. This is my code:

Controller:

```
ViewBag.Costo = "200";
return PartialView();
}
```

PartialView:

```
<h4>El costo de la entidad es: </h4>
@ViewBag.Costo
```

Comment: What is the error? Why can't you use it?

Comment: What error are you experiencing?

Comment: It does not give any error, just does not recognize the value of the property that I believe in the controller and pass it to the view and the latter does not take into account the property, it is as if it never existed, the same thing happens when I pass a list to a partial view in the view list and I get an error that the list is null when it is not .. I would greatly appreciate to solve this problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ViewBag in Main View , where partialview you have been rendered.